# \box\@labels and macrocode environment

Tags: lists, platex, doc

I'm not sure what `macrocode` environment intends to do with `\box\@labels`.

- Initially `\box\@labels` is void.
- When `macrocode` environment ends, it leaves some contents:

  > \box15=
  >   \hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
  >   .\glue 0.0
  >   .\glue 0.0
  >   .\glue -5.0
  >   .\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
  >   .\glue 5.0
- The content is still there when another list environment (say `itemize`) starts, and it is thrown away when the first `\item` appears.

MWE:

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname}
\end{document}
% \fi
%
% \makeatletter
% \tracingonline1
% \showboxdepth10000
% \showboxbreadth10000
%
% \showbox\@labels  ^^A -> void
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\MACRO{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \showbox\@labels  ^^A -> non-void???
%
% \begin{itemize}
% \showbox\@labels  ^^A -> non-void???
% \item a
% \showbox\@labels  ^^A -> void
% \item b
% \showbox\@labels  ^^A -> void
% \end{itemize}
%
% \showbox\@labels  ^^A -> void
%
\endinput
```

---

The reason why I'm asking is that we have the following issue in Japanese pLaTeX:

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage{plext}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname}
\end{document}
% \fi
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\MACRO{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \begin{minipage}<t>{10zw}
% The option `t' starts vertical writing.
% \begin{itemize}
% \item a
% \end{itemize}
% \end{minipage}
%
\endinput
```

This code generates an error:

```
! Incompatible direction list can't be unboxed.
\@item ...setbox \@labels \hbox {\unhbox \@labels 
                                                  \hskip \itemindent \hskip ...
l.17 % \item a

?
```

because `\box\@labels` is used inside tate (vertical-writing) but at that time it still contains yoko (horizontal-writing) nodes.

Comment: LaTeX team kindly addressed the problem: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/344#event-3571655913 Thanks!